# Div não alinha com o texto

Tags: html, css

Estou tentando alinha a div e o texto lado a lado, porém não funciona de jeito nenhum, já tentei float, tb, align e nada dá certo alguém por favor pode me dar um help.

```css
#sobre {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #0C0;
    background-size: cover;
}

.foto {
    width: 500px;
    height: 550px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

p.title {
    float: left;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-right: 225px;
    font-size: 80px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.infos {
    width: 400px;
    font-family: Arial;
    Helvetica,
    sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    background-color: #3CO;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="sobre">
    <p class="title">
        Sobre Mim:
    </p>
    <p class="infos">
        Etiam posuere quam ac quam. Maecenas aliquet accumsan leo. Nullam dapibus fermentum ipsum. Etiam quis quam. Integer lacinia. Nulla est. Nulla turpis magna, cursus sit amet, suscipit a, interdum id, felis. Integer vulputate sem a nibh rutrum consequat.
        Maecenas lorem. Pellentesque pretium lectus id turpis. Etiam sapien elit, consequat eget, tristique non, venenatis quis, ante. Fusce wisi. Phasellus faucibus molestie nisl. Fusce eget urna. Curabitur vitae diam non enim vestibulum interdum. Nulla
    </p>
</div>
```

jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/u7sa5sdc/4/

Comment: _"a div e o texto lado a lado"_ - como assim? o texto está dentro da div... queres dizer o `.title` e o `.infos` lado a lado?

Comment: Exatamente, eu gostaria que o .tittle e o .infos ficassem lado a lado.

Comment: `display: inline;`

Comment: @R.Ribeiro Assim? -> https://jsfiddle.net/u7sa5sdc/5/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Answer (score 2):

1) Você precisa definir uma largura pra que seus dois elementos apareçam lado a lado. Do contrário, tanto seu `.title` quanto seu `.info` terão 100% de largura e não ficarão lado a lado.

2) Defina uma largura pra cada elemento de forma com que ambos caibam em `100%` (no exemplo abaixo, cada `div` tem `50%` de largura) e retire as margens.

3) Crie uma classe helper chamada `clearfix` para limpar os seus elementos flutuantes logo no fim (exemplo no fiddle). O seu container (`#sobre`) perde a referência do conteúdo quando ele está abraçando elementos flutuantes.

4) Se você quiser dar uma margem pro seu elemento `.title`, por exemplo, será necessário colocar o `width` desse elemento subtraindo o valor da margem dada. Ex.:

```
p.title {
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u7sa5sdc/7/

Comment: Muito obrigado, era exatamente o que eu tava procurando. Upvoted

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é usar o `column-count` ou `column-width` na id `sobre`, e remover a `margin` do `p.title` e também o  `float`
Exemplo:

```
#sobre {
/* seu estilo aqui */
-webkit-column-count:2;
}

p.title{
/* seu estilo aqui */
margin:0;
}
```

O único problema é que pode ser necessário usar o prefixo de acordo com o navegador.
Mais info neste link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp